# How can I reassign `let` variables in client-side Tensorflow.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm doing a course on Tensorflow.js in Udemy which I've been really enjoying but I've come across a bug which has totally derailed me, namely that I don't seem to be able to reassign anything declared with a `let` keyword.

As far as I can tell this was raised as an issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/2765) but closed with a 'fix' of clearing cache and cookies, which has no effect for me. However, before I raise another issue I wanted to check here that I wasn't doing anything totally stupid. For context this is all just one big inline script in an `html` file. There are a few variables declared with `let` which are used for global scope, but whenever I try to reassign them Tensorflow thinks they're undefined.

Interestingly I get two different error messages on Chrome and Firefox:
Chrome: `Type Error: Cannot set property 'undefined' of undefined`
Firefox: `console.log(...) is undefined` (when trying to log one of the variables)

Relevant code snippets below:

```js
// very top of script here
let points
let normalisedFeature, normalisedLabel
let trainingFeatureTensor, testingFeatureTensor, trainingLabelTensor, testingLabelTensor

async function normalise(tensor, previousMin = null, previousMax = null) {
  const min = previousMin || tensor.min()
  const max = previousMax || tensor.max()
  const normalisedTensor = tensor.sub(min).div(max.sub(min))
  normalisedTensor.print(true)
  return {
    tensor: normalisedTensor,
    min,
    max
  }
}

// function that takes two of the problematic variables as args
async function trainModel (model, trainingFeatureTensor, trainingLabelTensor) {
  // not actually making it to here
}

// function that does some reassigning of the problematic variables
async function run () {
  // do some TF stuff, e.g. get a dataset


  const featureValues = points.map(p => p.x)
  const featureTensor = tf.tensor2d(featureValues, [featureValues.length, 1])

  // Extract Labels (outputs)
  const labelValues = points.map(p => p.y)
  const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labelValues, [labelValues.length, 1])

  // Normalise features and labels
  normalisedFeature = normalise(featureTensor)
  normalisedLabel = normalise(labelTensor)
  featureTensor.dispose()
  labelTensor.dispose()

  /**
  * I believe it's erroring here on Firefox
  * in Chrome this logs:
  * {tensor: e, min: e, max: e}
  */
  console.log('Normalised feature:\n', normalisedFeature)

  /**
  * I believe it's erroring here on Chrome
  */
  [trainingFeatureTensor, testingFeatureTensor] = tf.split(normalisedFeature.tensor, 2)
  [trainingLabelTensor, testingLabelTensor] = tf.split(normalisedLabel.tensor, 2)

  // Update status and enable train button
  document.getElementById("model-status").innerHTML = "No model trained"
  document.getElementById("train-button").removeAttribute("disabled")
  document.getElementById("load-button").removeAttribute("disabled")
}
```

Note I've omitted some code for brevity but hopefully everything relevant is there.

If anybody can point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

P.S. I've had code from previous modules on this course working, so I'm confident that I can get Tensorflow working in the browser generally.

P.P.S. My current version of the code is copy/pasted from the course solutions - I had been writing my own but tried the provided solution when mine wasn't working (with the error I've described in this question).

P.P.S. [Gist of whole code](https://gist.github.com/aNerdInTheHand/8bfa9fd21a6674e24051046e6071666d)

Comment: Where are you setting the values of `points` at?

Comment: In the `run` function, I just left it out so as not to have a huge code block - it's just a `map` of `x` and `y` values, I'm confident that's working ok

Comment: Ok could you include the function `normalise`?

Comment: Sorry yes I should have included that - have done now. Also note the comment I added that logging the normalised tensors in Chrome logs: `{tensor: e, min: e, max: e}` where presumably the `e` is an error but I'm struggling to dig any further into that

Answer (score 0):

So you are actually trying to access the value `normalisedTensor` but you access the entire object instead that is returned from the function `normalise`. To get the `normalisedTensor` only you can destructure the value from the returned object like this `const { normalisedTensor: normalisedFeature } = normalise(featureTensor);` where I also renamed it to `normalisedFeature`. This should fix the logging and the error being thrown from using `tf.split()` on the values `normalisedFeature` and `normalisedLabel`.

When mapping over the `points` I also used `points && points.map()` to make sure that you only map over the values if they are truthy values.

```
async function normalise(tensor, previousMin = null, previousMax = null) {
  const min = previousMin || tensor.min()
  const max = previousMax || tensor.max()
  const normalisedTensor = tensor.sub(min).div(max.sub(min))
  normalisedTensor.print(true)
  return {
    normalisedTensor,
    min,
    max
  }
}

async function run() {
  // "&&" is used to map over the points if it is a truthy value only
  const featureValues = points && points.map((p) => p.x);
  const featureTensor = tf.tensor2d(featureValues, [featureValues.length, 1]);

  const labelValues = points && points.map((p) => p.y);
  const labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labelValues, [labelValues.length, 1]);

  // Rename the returned value of normalisedTensor
  const { normalisedTensor: normalisedFeature } = normalise(featureTensor);
  const { normalisedTensor: normalisedLabel } = normalise(labelTensor);

  console.log("Normalised feature:\n", normalisedFeature);

  featureTensor.dispose();
  labelTensor.dispose();

  [(trainingFeatureTensor, testingFeatureTensor)] = tf.split(
    x = normalisedFeature,
    numOrSizeSplits = 2,
    axis = 0
  )
  [(trainingLabelTensor, testingLabelTensor)] = tf.split(
    x = normalisedLabel,
    numOrSizeSplits = 2,
    axis = 0
  );

  document.getElementById("model-status").innerHTML = "No model trained";
  document.getElementById("train-button").removeAttribute("disabled");
  document.getElementById("load-button").removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't actually work for me - I get an invalid destructuring error for the `const { normalisedTensor: ... }` line - but also I actually want the whole object returned from the `normalise` function as I use the `min` and `max` to call a `denormalise` function later. That's why on the `tf.split` I pass `normalisedTensor.tensor`, to just access the tensor that's returned. I realise it's hard to get all this from code snippets - I'm going to add the whole script! Appreciate if you have time to look but thanks for your help so far anyway.

Comment: @NickH that is odd I do not get the same error. Also if you want the other values you can just extract them like this `const { normalisedTensor: normalisedFeature, min, max } = normalise(featureTensor);`

Comment: I've added a link to a GitHub gist of the whole page so it's a bit clearer how the global variables are being used